# Immersive mode leaving slightly transparent white bar when hiding navigation

Tags: java, android, xml

When entering full screen immersive mode, [there is a lighter portion where the navigation bar was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9PUU.png)

Here is my XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.QuoteActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/din_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="&quot;Quote&quot;"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/din_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="- Author"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quote" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

These are the flags I use to enter immersive mode :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

This is my styles.xml :

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_2880x1440</item>

    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ls_2880x1440</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I am not using   `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`  anywhere in my program.

The white strip is not part of my background.

When I screenshot it, it goes away (image is recreation of what it looks like in app)

This also happens at the top but it is less noticeable.

So my question is, how do I get rid of this?

Comment: This sounds like burn-in to me. If the lighter stripe isn't present in a screenshot, it isn't "there" at all. Burn-in (or another physical problem with your display) is likely.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I checked on the photo app on my phone (pixel 2 xl), and it is still there. Can't believe I spent hours trying to solve a hardware problem...